# Optimising a process that looks for the shortest distance between case and control in multiples columnes of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, optimization, tidyverse

I need to optimise the following process to be applied to a dataframe dimensions 75000 x 10000:

I have observations (rows) named "id". These are controls. The elements in these rows represent distances between id and the respective Vx - where Vx is the name of the columns that go from V1...Vn and represent cases.

I need my algorithm to find the shorter distance between a pair of id and Vx. When one id has been selected into one of these pairs, it cannot be used again.

See this simple working example with my original code:

```
   library(dplyr)

#dummy data frame
df<-data.frame(V1=c(19,20,50), V2=c(23,22,21), V3=c(21.5,29,50),id=c(1,2,3))

#total of small elements that will be selected
numctrol<-1

#empty vectors to store outputs
control<-c()
case<-c()
distance<-c()

#-1 because last column is an ID column
for (i in 1:(ncol(df)-1)) {
         tmpc<-df
         tmpc.tmp<-tmpc %>% filter(tmpc[,i]>=1) 
         topctrol<- tmpc.tmp %>% arrange(tmpc.tmp[,i]) %>% head(numctrol) %>% pull(id)
         control<-c(control,topctrol)
         tmpdistance<-tmpc.tmp %>% filter(id %in% topctrol)  %>% pull(paste0('V',i))
         distance<-c(distance,tmpdistance)
         tmpcaseid<-rep(i,length(topctrol))
         case<-c(case,tmpcaseid)
}

newdf<-data.frame(case=case, control=control, distance=distance)
```

I have two problems with this code:

1. id 1 was selected twice as control (for case 1 and case 3)
2. It is extremely slow

What I'd like to obtain from my example above is the following

```
+-----+-----------+----------+
| case| control   | distance |
+-----+-----------+----------+
| 1   |         1 |   19     | 
| 2   |         3 |   21     |
| 3   |         2 |   29     | 
+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Let me explain it:

If you look dataframe df, for V1 (case 1 in my desired output) id 1 makes the shorter distance pair. id 1 does not make a shorter pair with any other case, so id1 is assigned to case 1.

for case 2, id3 makes the shorter pair. id3 does not make a shorter pair with case3, s I assign control 3 to case 2.

for case 3, the shorter pair is id 1. However, id1 makes the shorter pair with case1 and that's why it was assigned to that case. Then, the only option for case3 is to be pair with the second-best option which is id2.

Any help, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution and will leave it here in case someone else needs to do a similar thing. I will test it with my large dataset before accepting it. I need to check if this is quick enough to be used routinely.

The solution is a combination of long data - as suggested by Jakub.Novotny and a while loop.

See this reproducible example:

```
#dummy data
df<-data.frame(V1=c(19,20,50), V2=c(23,22,21), V3=c(21.5,29,50),id=c(1,2,3))


#long data values arranged from min to max
newdf <- df %>% pivot_longer(names_to = c("names"), values_to = "values", -id) %>% arrange(values)

#data frame with the expected size
output<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 3))

#dummies that are used within while loop
i=1
m=0

while (i <= nrow(newdf)) {
  
  #take first set with shorter distance between case and control
  a<-newdf %>% slice(1)  
  #allocate case,control and distance in the output dataframe
  output[m+i,]<-a 
  #remove case and control from newdf
  newdf<-newdf %>% filter(!names==a$names) %>% filter(!id==a$id) 

  i=1  #look to first row in newdf again
  m=m+1 #store first row in the following row in output data frame
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along these lines:

```
newdf <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = "names", values_to = "values", -id) %>%
  group_by(names) %>%
  slice_min(order_by = values, n = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It made me realise that my question is actually more complex than originally proposed.  I edited my question.

Your approach is quick though! - 18 min in my laptop - not bad.

Comment: What you ask is non trivial. I would recommend transforming the data in the long format (as I did with pivot_longer), and then perform a loop looking for min values for each case, and subsequently filtering out the "used" ids.

Comment: Good idea. Thank you. I think I found a solution